# how to properly use fwrite and while function in php

Tags: php, while-loop, fwrite

here is my php code to create another file :

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$category = $_POST['category'];

$b = './'.$title.".html";

$a = fopen("$b", "w");

fwrite($a, $title);
fwrite($a, $location);
fwrite($a, $category);

fclose($a);
```

here are only a few lines of variable and I have many more variables that will need to be written.
my question is how do I efficiently use the while function so that i don't need to keep repeating fwrite so many times, or please teach me a better way to do this..?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post all your variables in a array like this:

```
$vararr[] = $_POST['title'];
$vararr[] = $_POST['location'];

foreach($vararr as $data){
   fwrite($a, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to read in all lines and create an array of it. Afterwards you can simply write the lines to another file again.

```
$file = fopen('file.txt', 'w');

foreach ($yourLines as $lines)
{
    fwrite($file, $lines->getAttribute('id') . "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion,
you could add your lines into an array and add it this way for example:

```
$file = fopen('file.txt', 'w');
foreach ($yourValues as $lines)
{
    fwrite($file, $lines->getAttribute('id') . "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take all the form values once in array and than loop through it.

```
    $data = array();
    foreach($POST as $key => $value){
      $data[$key] = $value;
    }

    foreach($data as $key => $line){
    $string = "$key = $line";
    fwrite($a, $string);
    }
```